# Apache Netbeans 11.0 not appearing in Add/Remove Programs Windows 10

Tags: netbeans

I installed Apache Netbeans a couple weeks ago, decided I didn't like it, and am attempting to uninstall it.  However, it is not showing up in my Add/Remove Programs on Windows 10, nor can I find an Uninstall exe file in the files of NetBeans.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You must have installed Apache NetBeans 11.0 by downloading a zip file named **incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin.zip**, then unzipping it to an installation directory, because that is the only approach that is offered. [From the Apache NetBeans web site](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html):

> Apache NetBeans 11.0 is available for download from your closest
>   Apache mirror. **For this release no official installers are provided,
>   please just download the binaries and unzip them**.

This explains why you cannot uninstall NetBeans 11.0 from the Control Panel in Windows 10: you did not install it using an installer, you just unzipped a file.

So to uninstall NetBeans 11.0 on Windows 10 all you need to do is this:

- Close NetBeans.
- Delete the NetBeans installation directory.
- Delete the downloaded zip file (if you had kept it).

However, there are a couple of additional optional steps that will free up (a lot of) disk space, and are definitely worth doing:

- Before removing/uninstalling NetBeans, open it one last time.
- Open the **Help > About** screen. You will see a couple of entries named **User directory** and **Cache directory**. They contain (a lot of) files related to the configuration of NetBeans, and they can and should be deleted as well:

  [image: HelpAbout]
- Note the names of those two directories, and then close NetBeans.
- Delete those two directories, and then delete the NetBeans installation directory and the downloaded zip file (if necessary).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution!  I appreciate the fast response!

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu. I used build and install as [https://github.com/apache/netbeans](https://github.com/apache/netbeans)